# jQuery UI Draggable into Fixed Position Container?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a simple example where I am trying to drag an element inside another element with a fixed position.  Once I drop the element inside the fixed (or absolute) position container, the element is no longer draggable.

Does anyone have any thoughts?  I'm thinking this might be a bit of an issue if any fixed/absolute positioned containers cause draggable elements not to function properly.  See my JS Bin.

http://jsbin.com/igiqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has actually nothing to do with the `fixed` position.

Your draggable element has a lower *implicit z-index* based on the DOM tree. So when you drag it onto the drag area, it is *below* it.

Give it an explicit `z-index` so it is frontmost:

```
.box
{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #c40000;
    background-color: #c40000;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/2e2Aj/)**